# Highcharts Highmaps How to add mappoint to custom map

Tags: highcharts

I built a custom map with Highmaps: [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/xgwuznse/3/)

Now I want to add a series with map points:

```
{
        type: 'mappoint',
        name: 'Cities',
        zIndex: 100,
        color: '#000000',
        data: [{
            name: 'Birmingham',
            lat: 52,
            lon: 1.8
            }]
    }
```

But I do not know how to use fromLatLonToPoint in this case. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use lat and lon properties, but your `mappoint` series is overwritten with parsed series from `data` property. As a soulution, use the `addSeries` method after the main data is loaded, for example:

```
 parsed: function() {
   var chart = this.chart,
     center = chart.fromLatLonToPoint({
       lat: 50,
       lon: 10
     });

   setTimeout(function() {
     chart.mapZoom(.15, center.x, center.y);

     chart.addSeries({
       type: 'mappoint',
       name: 'Cities',
       zIndex: 100,
       color: '#000000',
       data: [{
         name: 'Birmingham',
         lat: 52,
         lon: 1.8
       }]
     });
   }, 500)
 }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vw1p4jtr/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.data.lat

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek it works, but the data labels are displayed outside the plot area: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/xgwuznse/6/) Can you tell me how to prevent this?

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, Thanks for the example. As a solution, enable the `crop` property. Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e7hym0dL/